# How to create a background-color highlighting box which reaches outside the text column [picture provided]

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create a column of text, consisting of a series of blocks of text, where one of the blocks has a coloured background which reaches outside the column. I'd like to do this in two different ways, first where the text layout is unaffected, second where there is extra bounding space:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UJWiNwk.png]

I suspect this should be a lot easier than I'm making it.

I've been trying to do the first by surrounding each block with a div element, with a margin of 10px, and then for the highlighted block, setting a margin of 0px, and padding of 10px.

This works well for normal paragraphs. The problem is, when the block of text starts with a heading (say, an h3 heading), padding for the bottom, left and bottom works well, but the top padding adds more than is wanted, and it can't even be manually tweaked, because there's a very large jump between padding-top:1px and padding-top:0px.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <p>
        Test Test Test Test Test Test
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block test2-block">
        <h3>Test Title</h3>
        Test2 Test Test Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>
        Test3 Test Test Test Test Test
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    .block {
        margin:10px;
    }
    .test2-block {
        background-color:green;
        margin:0px;
        padding-right:10px;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        /*This value can't be tweaked manually, try 0, 1, and 10 pixel values*/
        padding-top:10px;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

I'm not sure at all how to go about the undisturbed layout. Could someone give me a pointer?

Edit: Thanks to aaronegan and sfyn below, that's the solution for the extra bounding space (right hand on picture). If anyone knows how to maintain an undisturbed layout (left hand on picture), that would be superb. Does this require the same sort of trick - manually altering the margin-bottom for the paragraph above the highlighted block, and margin-top for the paragraph below? I was hoping to be able to do this dynamically - to add a flash-then-fade background when scrolling to an anchor link. You could dynamically alter both the block itself, the paragraph below, and the paragraph above, but it seems awkward.

Comment: Does adding this style rule do what you had in mind? `.test2-block h3 { margin-top: 0; }` - http://jsfiddle.net/eM3BC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting a width for your column first at a fixed amount of pixels or using a width % of any divs it sits in.

The issue arising with your h3 is that by default, it has a margin-top attribute. So although the p's look nice, the h3 has extra space at the top due to this.

Here's what I did:

- Set a width for your column in your css (whatever you want)
- Remove the unnecessary padding-bottom/top/right/left from your
  .test2-block class and just have padding 10px
- Override the h3 margin-top in your CSS with this:

  ```
  .block {
      margin:10px;
      width:200px;
  }

  .test2-block {
      background-color:green;
      margin:0px;
      padding:10px;
  }

  .test2-block h3 {
      margin-top:0px;
  }
  ```

[Working JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3ta/1/)